# Gridview SelectedIndex value set

Tags: asp.net

Work on Asp.Net C# .

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CategoryID"
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" InsertVisible="False"
                                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
   GridView2.FindControl("CategoryID").Text=2;
```

}

want selected column value change on ridView2_SelectedIndexChanged method .How to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access to your selected row cells content by `GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text`

Comment: i know that.i want to know how to change the gridview cell value .